# PHP make sure that a file is called only from a certain server

Tags: php, curl

I have a php script that's on another server and i call it using `curl`. As we know the `$_SERVER` variable can be spoofed so, therefore, what options do i have to identify the server from which my script was called?

Is there actually something uniq that can't be spoofed into the `$_SERVER` variable?

P.S i would like to avoid using a `token` like in `?token=xyz`

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with using basic auth or similar?

Comment: @fubar, nothing, just wondering if there's some other way.

Comment: Ah okay. I don’t think there is going to be a fool proof method other than some form of authentication. Be that basic auth, or some token generated with a public and private key.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. 
As a ‘less-tokenized’ solution you could generate a ‘decryptable’ hash on your response, decrypt it and validate that it has an expected value.